# How do I loop over a slice of an array using ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, slice, ngfor

I am creating a FAQ page with accordion buttons, with groups of buttons under sub-headers.  I designed it using an **ngFor** statement in the faq.html file.

```
<h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
<div *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index;">
    <button class="accordion" (click)="toggleAccordion($event, i)"> {{item.parentName}} </button>
    <div class="panel" *ngFor="let child of item.childProperties" hide="!item.isActive">
    <p> {{child.propertyName}} </p>
</div>
```

Here is a snippet of the faq.ts file.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-faq',
  templateUrl: './faq.html',
  styleUrls: ['./faq.scss']
})
export class FaqComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any = [
    {
      parentName: 'Question 1A',
      childProperties: [{ propertyName: 'Answer 1A' }],
    },
    {
      parentName: 'Question 2A',
      childProperties: [{ propertyName: 'Answer 2A' }],
    },
    {
      parentName: 'Question 3A',
      childProperties: [{ propertyName: 'Answer 3A' }],
    },
    {
      parentName: 'Question 1B',
      childProperties: [{ propertyName: 'Answer 1B' }],
    },
    {
      parentName: 'Question 2B',
      childProperties: [{ propertyName: 'Answer 2B' }],
    },
  ];
}
```

I want to put sub-headers over Section A (Questions 1A, 2A, and 3A), and Section B (Questions 1B and 2B).  I think I can use **slice** in the **ngFor** statement in faq.html, but the code won't compile.

I tried this slice pipe:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of data | slice:0:2; let i = index;">
```

What should I change to get it to compile and break up the FAQ sections?  Is the slice pipe the way to go?

Answer (score 4):

#### Slicing Your Data

The problem here is that the slice pipe returns your data as type `unknown`. There are a couple of ways around this:

#### $any

```html
<p *ngFor="let item of data | slice:2:4">
  {{ $any(item).parentName }}
</p>
```

#### Bracket notation

```html
<p *ngFor="let item of data | slice:2:4">
  {{ item['parentName'] }}
</p>
```

#### A function

```
slicedData(data : any[]) : any[] {
  return data.slice(2,4)
}
```

```html
<p *ngFor="let item of slicedData(data)">
  {{ item['parentName'] }}
</p>
```

*You might want to properly type your data though, instead of using any. It is called Typescript for a reason after all.*

Here are some examples in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h9k6sl?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this out.

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the html to access the properties in different way and it got compiled:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index;">
    <button class="accordion" (click)="toggleAccordion($event, i)"> {{item['parentName']}} </button>
    <div class="panel" *ngFor="let child of item['childProperties'] | slice:0:2; let i = index;" hide="!item.isActive">
    <p> {{child['propertyName']}} </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add one `*ngIf` and check if `i < 3`:

```html
<h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
<div *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index;">
  <ng-container *ngIf="i < 3">
    <button class="accordion" (click)="toggleAccordion($event, i)"> {{item.parentName}} </button>
    <div class="panel" *ngFor="let child of item.childProperties" hide="!item.isActive">
    <p> {{child.propertyName}} </p>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help, everyone.  I changed faq.html to:

```
<h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
<h2>General</h2>
<div *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index;">
  <ng-container *ngIf="i < 3">
    <button class="accordion" (click)="toggleAccordion($event, i)"> {{item.parentName}} </button>
    <div class="panel" hide="!item.isActive">
    <p> {{item.childName}} </p>
</div>
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your .ts component, declare your variable as below

```
data: any[] = [
    {
        parentName: 'Question 1A',
        childProperties: [{ propertyName: 'Answer 1A' }],
    },
    {
        parentName: 'Question 2A',
        childProperties: [{ propertyName: 'Answer 2A' }],
    },
    {
        parentName: 'Question 3A',
        childProperties: [{ propertyName: 'Answer 3A' }],
    },
    {
        parentName: 'Question 1B',
        childProperties: [{ propertyName: 'Answer 1B' }],
    },
    {
        parentName: 'Question 2B',
        childProperties: [{ propertyName: 'Answer 2B' }],
    },
];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).